# Overwrite Core Data if it exists

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I've been working on some Core Data app and just did some other apps for practice.

I've been getting tons of help from everyone around the webs so thanks in advance.

I have this app that does nothing really but it's just a `Core Data + CollectionView` practice.

Anyways, you're supposed to Add a new `DataThing` and it saves it into core data and then displays it in a `CollectionView`.

If you click on that collection view you load the view controller (the one used to add new ones) but it gets pre-loaded with the data (or that's the intent).

At the end, when you "add" before actually adding, the app checks if an entry with that title already exists, if it does it should overwrite it, else it should save a new one.

Here's the code that displays/loads the `UICollectionView` (note the function "did select" is commented out since it crashes):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var addEntryBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var xtraBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let myAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    var thingsLoaded: [DataThing]?
    @IBAction func addEntryTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addEntrySegue", sender: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func xtraTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //might be used to load?
        viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let context = myAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DataThing")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do
        {
            thingsLoaded = try context.fetch(request) as? [DataThing]
            print ("Data Loaded")
        }
        catch
        {
            print ("Error Reading Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
}


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return thingsLoaded?.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCVCell

        if thingsLoaded != nil
        {
            customCell.titleLabel.text = thingsLoaded![indexPath.row].title
            customCell.numberLabel.text = thingsLoaded![indexPath.row].number
            customCell.noteLabel.text = thingsLoaded![indexPath.row].note

            if thingsLoaded![indexPath.row].active {
            customCell.statusView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        } else {
            customCell.statusView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }

        }

        return customCell
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // THIS WHOLE CHUNK OF CODE CREATES FATAL ERROR, FOUND NIL WHILE UNWRAPPING.

        /*
        let loadEntryVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loadEntry") as! EntryVC
        loadEntryVC.isActive.isOn = thingsLoaded![indexPath.row].active
        loadEntryVC.titleText.text = thingsLoaded![indexPath.row].title
        loadEntryVC.numberText.text = thingsLoaded![indexPath.row].number
        loadEntryVC.noteText.text = thingsLoaded![indexPath.row].note
        loadEntryVC.titleText.isEnabled = false

        self.present(loadEntryVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 */
    }

}
```

Here's The code for the "Add Entry" View Controller. Note, I commented out the part that makes the game crash which calls a custom fetch function:

```
class EntryVC: UIViewController {
    var delegate: DeezNutsDelegate?
    let myAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    @IBOutlet weak var titleText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var noteText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var isActive: UISwitch!

    @IBOutlet weak var addBtn: UIButton!

    @IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let context = myAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DataThing")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


//        if let checkExist = DataThing.findByTitle(titleText.text!)
//        {
//            print ("HELLO WORLD!") NOTE JUST CALLING THE FUNCTION IN THIS SIMPLE MANNER MAKES THE APP CRASH.
//        }

        //check that this doesnt exist
//        if let existingData = DataThing.findByTitle(titleText.text ?? "")
//        {
//            print ("DATA FOUND")
//            //data already exists
//            existingData.active = isActive.isOn
//            existingData.number = numberText.text ?? "NA"
//            existingData.note = noteText.text ?? "No Entry"
//
//            print ("DATA OVEWRITTEN")
//        } else {
            print ("DATA DOES NOT EXISt, ATTEMPING NEW ONE!")
            if let dataThing = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "DataThing", into: context) as? DataThing {
            dataThing.active = isActive.isOn
            dataThing.title = titleText.text ?? "No Entry"
            dataThing.number = numberText.text ?? "N.A."
            dataThing.note = noteText.text ?? "No Entry"

            print ("DATA STORED!")
        }
        //}

        do
        {
            try context.save()
            print ("CoreData: Game Saved!")
        }
        catch
        {
            print ("Error Saving Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

and Finally, here's that custom function that fetches `DataThings`:

```
class func findByTitle(_ title: String) -> DataThing? {
        let myAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = myAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DataThing")
        let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = \(title)", argumentArray: nil)
        request.predicate = idPredicate
        var result: [AnyObject]?
        var dataThingFound: DataThing? = nil
        do {
            result = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error getting data: \(error)")
            result = nil
        }
        if result != nil {
            for resultItem : AnyObject in result! {
                dataThingFound = resultItem as? DataThing
                print ("DATA FOUND, RETURNING IT!")
            }
        }
        return dataThingFound
    }
```

**EDIT**
heres' the crash code for the "fetch by Title" crashing

```
2018-01-16 12:42:47.189960+0800 CoreData+Collections[819:9224] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath title2 not found in entity <NSSQLEntity DataThing id=1>'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110a4112b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c7e8f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreData                            0x000000010d1b1c71 -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:nestIsWhereScoped:requestContext:] + 1649
    3   CoreData                            0x000000010d1bc880 -[NSSQLiteAdapter _statementForFetchRequestContext:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 144
    4   CoreData                            0x000000010d079c12 -[NSSQLiteAdapter newSelectStatementWithFetchRequestContext:ignoreInheritance:] + 130
    5   CoreData                            0x000000010d1fe613 -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext _createStatement] + 67
    6   CoreData                            0x000000010d1fe5bc -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext fetchStatement] + 172
    7   CoreData                            0x000000010d1ff63b -[NSSQLFetchRequestContext executeRequestCore:] + 27
    8   CoreData                            0x000000010d26449c -[NSSQLStoreRequestContext executeRequestUsingConnection:] + 204
    9   CoreData                            0x000000010d23955b __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke + 75
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111b6333d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111b6a235 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 392
    12  CoreData                            0x000000010d239443 -[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:] + 339
    13  CoreData                            0x000000010d241294 -[NSSQLCoreDispatchManager routeStoreRequest:] + 308
    14  CoreData                            0x000000010d1976c5 -[NSSQLCore dispatchRequest:withRetries:] + 229
    15  CoreData                            0x000000010d1945fd -[NSSQLCore processFetchRequest:inContext:] + 93
    16  CoreData                            0x000000010d07915b -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 571
    17  CoreData                            0x000000010d17a08b __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 1691
    18  CoreData                            0x000000010d17221a -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:] + 378
    19  CoreData                            0x000000010d078ac4 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 660
    20  CoreData                            0x000000010d0770e4 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 564
    21  libswiftCoreData.dylib              0x000000010fe72f1a _T0So22NSManagedObjectContextC8CoreDataE5fetchSayxGSo14NSFetchRequestCyxGKSo0gH6ResultRzlF + 58
    22  CoreData+Collections                0x000000010beb2f81 _T020CoreData_Collections0B5ThingC11findByTitleACSgSSFZ + 1105
    23  CoreData+Collections                0x000000010bebc92d _T020CoreData_Collections7EntryVCC9addTappedyypF + 1069
    24  CoreData+Collections                0x000000010bebe6f8 _T020CoreData_Collections7EntryVCC9addTappedyypFTo + 72
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010d5d3972 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010d752c3c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010d752f59 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010d751e86 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010d649807 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010d64af2a -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010d5ee365 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    32  UIKit                               0x000000010df3aa1d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010df3d672 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109e4101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110a83f71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109c8a19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109c7fff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001109c7889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    39  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001131e59c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    40  UIKit                               0x000000010d5d25d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    41  CoreData+Collections                0x000000010bebaea7 main + 55
    42  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111bdfd81 start + 1
    43  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: my Fetch Request keeps crashing. I forgot to add the crash text. *EDITED just now* I guess the question is "can you help me find whats wrong with the code?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fetch request never returns quite unspecified `AnyObject`. It returns at least `[NSFetchRequestResult]` and if the *generic* request is more specified the result is more specified: That's the benefit of generics.

I recommend to make `findByTitle` an instance method which `throws` an error as you are using a `do - catch` block anyway. The method takes the requested `title` and the context as parameters. The method returns:

- If the object is found return the (non-optional) object.
- If the object is not found insert a new one assign the title and return that.
- If an error occurs the error is thrown (passed through).

  ```
  func find(byTitle title: String, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws -> DataThing {
      let request = NSFetchRequest<DataThing>(entityName: "DataThing")
      request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", title)
      let result = try context.fetch(request)
      if let dataThing = result.first {
          return dataThing
      } else {
          let dataThing = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "DataThing", into: context) as! DataThing
          dataThing.title = title
          return dataThing
      }
  }
  ```

In `addTapped` first check if the text field is empty. then call `find(byTitle` and assign the other values:

```
@IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let myAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = myAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    guard let title = titleText.text, !title.isEmpty else { return }
    do {
        let dataThing = try find(byTitle:  title, in: context)
        dataThing.active = isActive.isOn
        dataThing.number = numberText.text ?? "NA"
        dataThing.note = noteText.text ?? "No Entry"
        try context.save()
        print ("CoreData: Game Saved!")
    }  catch {
        print ("Error Saving Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that does the trick. I have a question tho, when you declare find(byTitle title:String... I originally thought you made a typ-O and was supposed to be findByTitle (title:string... would this method work as well? I mean my question is what is byTitle title mean? I thought you had to do <VAR NAME>: <VAR TYPE> and if that's the case, what is "byTitle" for?

Comment: also, if I may ask another question based on your code you just posted. If I try to use your fetch request to delete. I tried the following code: `let result = try context.fetch(request)
            if let dataThing = result.first {
                context.delete(result) // Cannot convert value of type [DataThing] to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'
                print("Entry deleted!")
            }` however it gives me that error (i commented the error)

Comment: 1) It's just another way to name the method, your way works as well 2) You have to delete `dataThing` (the single object) rather than `result` (the array). That's what the error message says.